# Return delta from SAP OData Sample service

Tags: odata, sap-gateway

I am trying to extract data from a SAP's Basic Sample Service via OData, I [registered](https://help.sap.com/viewer/68bf513362174d54b58cddec28794093/7.51.6/en-US/59283fc4528f486b83b1a58a4f1063c0.html). It is working fine in 'normal mode' and is returning like 302 records. What I am failing to get is data in delta mode with like 20 records, instead it is still returning 302 records.

I am hitting this [URL](https://sapes5.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/iwbep/GWSAMPLE_BASIC/SalesOrderSet?(%270500000001%27)/ToLineItems). To get data in delta mode I am sending this header `Prefer: odata.maxpagesize=20,odata.track-changes`

I am very new to this, so please pardon me if I have missed something. Any kind of help would be very appreaciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this annotation is [not implemented](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12637366/odata-change-tracking-on-hana-repository.html) in SAP implementation of Odata, so you are out of the luck. It is [supported](https://help.sap.com/viewer/107a6e8a38b74ede94c833ca3b7b6f51/2.0.3/en-US/50f4ee6253134d3cafa25b9444f0c5a9.html) though in ODP, but not in Gateway OData.

To enable delta tracking in OData service SAP has its own guidelines:

1. Generating delta token
2. Extend GET_ENTITYSET_DELTA method
3. First OData query on entity set will return a delta token
4. Which you then use to query delta

   ```
   /sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGW_PRODUCT_SRV/Products_DQ?!deltatoken=’005056A2025C1EE2BFE687AFDC2FAAF4_20130807073741′
   ```

Read this official guide for more info

https://blogs.sap.com/2013/09/30/how-to-implement-basic-delta-query-support-in-sap-netweaver-gateway/

Minimum GW required version: Netweaver 740, SAP_GWFND SP04

Comment: thanks for the answer man. I was out of luck search about it on web.

Comment: does this require changes on server side? I don't have access to those

Comment: yes it does, you need to implement delta handling in service implementation (pt2), also if this service is published using annotation `@odata.publish true` so it doesn't support custom handling and you are out of the luck as well